# Gulp tasking my connect server but show error things

Tags: gulp

sorry!My english is very poor!If you can't understanding my meaning!read more times  please! Thank you very much!
here is my codes:

```
gulp.task('server', function () {

    connect.server({
        livereload: true,
        port: 8000
    });
});
```

When i in terminal running gulp server,the screen shows  following pictures:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPlWX.png)

it shows not my defined routes,it's  my file's directory!but i don't konw why!
so ,help me !Thanks a lot!

Another question is:

I cannot open my index.html file in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

it's all because this is node a nodejs server. This gulp server is used to serve static assets and html files.

to run this code you might need to use the following command

```
node server.js
```

Comment: I know  what your mean.but  what puzzled me is that i have  been created a   server.js  file.i just don't know how to use gulp to start it.

Comment: I think you might use this npm package to start a node server from gulp

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-develop-server